# Regex which returns filenames without suffix

Tags: regex

I'm using a BPM software to automate some process, and in my flow I need to group some files  according with their names.

I need create a regular expression which returns project name without suffix.
The greater problem is the 'Foo_Bar' part in the name of file, it changes in each project.

I'm trying to solve it using a lookahead regex, but for any reason it didn't works.

It's possible solve this kind of problem using a regex?

```
var arr = [
    'Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar_Barcoded_Layout-1.pdf',
    'Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar_Barcoded_Layout-2.pdf',
    'Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar_Layout-1.pdf',
    'Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar_Layout-2.pdf',
    'Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar.xml',
    'Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar_Report.pdf'
];

re = /Company-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\w+(?=_Barcoded|_Layout|_Report|\.)/;

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var match = arr[i].match(re);
    var str = match ? match[0] : null
    console.log(str);
}�
```

Output:

```
Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar_Barcoded
Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar_Barcoded
Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar
Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar
Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar
Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar_Report�
```

Output expected:

```
Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar
Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar
Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar
Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar
Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar
Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar�
```

Comment: Try with `\w+?` in the middle. By default, *GREP is greedy* and will attempt to match as much as possible.

Comment: I'll elaborate a little on Jongware's comment: What's happening is that your pattern consumes the entire string up to `Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar_Barcoded_Layout` (because of the `\w+`). Then it backs up until the lookahead assertion no longer fails, which is at `Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar_Barcoded`. If you change it to `\w+?`, it will match character by character until the assertion succeeds, which is at `Company-2014-09-19_Foo_Bar`, giving you the desired result.

Comment: Thank you guys!

\w+? solved my problem!

Thank you very much Jongware for the tip, and Rawing for the excelent explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this expression:

```
(Company-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\w+?)(?:_Barcoded|_Layout|_Report)*(?:-\d+)?(?:\.\w+)
```

[Regex101 demo: PHP/PCRE](http://regex101.com/r/fR7vT4/1)
[Regex101 demo: Javascript](http://regex101.com/r/fR7vT4/2)